# How to interpret glmer output?

Tags: r, probability, lme4, mixed-models, interpretation

I conducted a mixed `linear logit model` with the `glmer` function. Now I have the results and have no clue how to interpret them.

```
Fixed effects:
                      Estimate      
(Intercept)             5.5433     
Condition              -0.8081     
Probability            -4.8688     
Condition:Probability   0.4881
```

Condition contains the two values -1 and 1.
Probability contains all values between 0 and 1.

How can I interpret these values? How can I get the `logits` into a probability?
For example: Condition is -1 and Probability is 1. What is the main effect for condition as a probability?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research if found out by myself how to interpret the data.
(Btw the condition is binary coded)

Here is the answer:

First, you calculate the predicted value like this:

L = intercept + b1 * condition + b2*probability + b3*condition*probability.
Then you can calculate the probabiliy: Pr(Y=1)  = 1/(1+exp(-L))

For my example: 
Condition is -1 and Probability is 1.
L= 5,54 + (-0.81*-1) + (-4.87*1) + (0.49*(-1)*1) = 0.99

Convert the Logit into Probability: Pr(Y=1)  = 1/(1+exp(-0.99)) = 0.73

For condition -1 and probability 1 the calculatet probability is 73%